# Bitbucket test step failed when micronaut discovery client dependency is added in build.gradle

Tags: micronaut, bitbucket-pipelines

I have Micronauts service which is up and running, now I want to change my data source values into the config map, added below lines in build.gradle.
implementation("io.micronaut.kubernetes:micronaut-kubernetes-discovery-client")
implementation("io.micronaut.kubernetes:micronaut-kubernetes-client")

Now when the test step runs in bitbucket pipeline it fails with below error

```
16:03:59.973 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Required property [consul.client] with value [null] not present
16:03:59.973 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Configuration: io.micronaut.discovery.vault.config.v1 will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
16:03:59.973 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Required property [vault.client.kv-version] with value [V1] not present
16:03:59.973 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Configuration: io.micronaut.discovery.vault.config.v2 will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
16:03:59.973 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Required property [vault.client.kv-version] with value [V2] not present
16:03:59.987 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Bean [io.micronaut.liquibase.$GormMigrationRunnerDefinition] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
16:03:59.987 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Class [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore] is not present
16:03:59.987 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Bean [io.micronaut.liquibase.$$GormMigrationRunnerDefinition$InterceptedDefinition] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
16:03:59.987 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Class [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore] is not present
16:03:59.989 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Bean [io.micronaut.rabbitmq.metrics.$RabbitMetricsInterceptor$Definition] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
16:03:59.989 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Class [io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry] is not present
16:03:59.996 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Bean [Definition: io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.TransactionAwareDataSource] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
16:03:59.996 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Existing bean [io.micronaut.jdbc.spring.DataSourceTransactionManagerFactory] of type [class io.micronaut.jdbc.spring.DataSourceTransactionManagerFactory] registered in context
16:03:59.997 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Bean [io.micronaut.web.router.version.$VersionAwareRouterListener$Definition] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
16:03:59.997 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Required property [micronaut.router.versioning.enabled] with value [true] not present
16:04:00.025 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Bean [io.micronaut.transaction.jdbc.$DelegatingDataSourceResolver$Definition] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
16:04:00.026 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager] is not absent
16:04:00.089 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Bean [io.micronaut.reactor.convert.$ReactorToRxJava3ConverterRegistrar$Definition] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
16:04:00.089 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Class [io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Maybe] is not present
16:04:00.090 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Bean [io.micronaut.http.netty.channel.converters.$KQueueChannelOptionFactory$Definition] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
16:04:00.090 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Class [io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueue] is not present
16:04:00.091 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Bean [io.micronaut.reactive.flow.converters.$FlowConverterRegistrar$Definition] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
16:04:00.091 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Class [kotlinx.coroutines.reactive.ReactiveFlowKt] is not present
16:04:00.098 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Bean [io.micronaut.http.netty.channel.converters.$EpollChannelOptionFactory$Definition] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
16:04:00.098 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Class [io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll] is not present
16:04:00.099 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Bean [io.micronaut.http.netty.channel.converters.$EpollChannelOptionFactory$Definition] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
16:04:00.099 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Class [io.netty.channel.epoll.Epoll] is not present
16:04:00.100 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Bean [io.micronaut.http.netty.channel.converters.$KQueueChannelOptionFactory$Definition] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
16:04:00.100 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Class [io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueue] is not present
16:04:00.100 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Bean [io.micronaut.http.netty.channel.converters.$KQueueChannelOptionFactory$Definition] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
16:04:00.100 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Class [io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueue] is not present
16:04:00.214 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - Bean [io.micronaut.logging.$PropertiesLoggingLevelsConfigurer$Definition] will not be loaded due to failing conditions:
16:04:00.214 [Test worker] DEBUG i.m.context.condition.Condition - * Required property [logger.levels] with value [null] not present
16:04:00.223 [Test worker] WARN  i.m.k.c.DefaultNamespaceResolver - An error has occurred when reading the file: [/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace]. Kubernetes namespace will be set to: default
16:04:00.647 [OkHttp http://localhost:8080/...] ERROR i.m.k.client.OkHttpClientLogging - HTTP FAILED: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080
```

In my local gradlew clean test is working the same command is not working in pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added conditional dependency in build.gradle for Micronauts discovery client, and when run test with that condition from bitbucket pipeline.